# Can Outlook 2010 show upcoming subscribed calendar appointments in mail view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, google-calendar

My calendar is hosted with Google and viewed through Outlook as an Internet Calendar Subscription. This means it's read only and doesn't update very frequently, but I'm fine with that.

The problem is that when I look at my inbox, the next calendar appointments only show the ones in my local calendar. Tonight I'm going out for drinks with friends but if you looked at this, you'd have no idea:

[image]

Is there any way to configure this so it shows all the upcoming ones from all my calendars?

Failing that, is there any way to configure is so that a different (internet calendar subscription) is shown instead?

Comment: You can not have both the Outlook and external calendars display simultaneously. The only way I know to do this is to change your default data file, which affects calendar, email and task. Is that something you are willing to do?

Comment: I'm not sure, do you know what the ramifications are of doing this? A quick Google search suggests that it's not possible to get rid of the Outlook default data file.